# Fancybox and Meteor, absolute URL

Tags: javascript, url, meteor, fancybox, iron-router

I trying to use this config of fancybox, for show the images from any selector, but I change the `href:'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg'` for `href:'/image/example/1.jpg'` doesn't work, I dont know how to show the absolute URL here with Meteor someone can help?

```
 $("selector").click(function() {       
      $.fancybox.open([
          {
            href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
            title : 'manual 1st title'
          },
          {
              href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg',
              title : '2nd title'
          },
          {
              href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg',
              title : '3rd title'
          }
      ], {
      nextEffect  : 'fade',
      prevEffect  : 'fade',
      openEffect  : 'elastic',
      closeEffect : 'fade',
      scrolling   : 'visible',
      type        : 'image',
      autoSize    : true,
      padding     : 0,
      helpers     : {
        title : {
          type    : 'over'  
        }            
      }
  });
      return false;
    });
```

I have this into a `Template.publicogeneral.rendered = function()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use vanilla javascript for this: `window.location.origin` will give you the current hostname with protocol (and port if non-standard). So you'll want something like:

```
...
$.fancybox.open([
  {
    href: `${window.location.origin}/image/example/1.jpg`,
    title: 'manual 1st title'
  },
...
```